# VB.NET string manipulation

Tags: vb.net, string

Looking for the simplest way to extract values from a string. For example consider the following:

```
Dim args As String = "/firstname:Bob /lastname:Jones"
```

To simplify, I need to be able to popup a box that says "Firstname = Bob" or "Lastname = Jones"

Comment: @Gens: I only wish. Little too old for homework :)

Comment: Could try something like this to do the work for you? (Assuming you're parsing command line args) http://commandline.codeplex.com/ or http://nconsoler.csharpus.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the Split method on a string.  It should look something like this:

```
Dim arr() as string
arr=args.Split("/")
Dim i as integer
    For i=0 to arr.GetLength(0)
    arr(i)=arr(i).Trim.Replace(":", "=")
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Split function to create an array of words, then read them in order:

```
char[] sep = new char[2];
sep[0] = '/';
sep[1] = ':';
string values = "/firstname:Bob /lastname:Jones";
string[] sites = values.Split(sep);
foreach (string s in sites) {
Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

This post is also useful!
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/easily-parse-string-values-with-net/6030362

Comment: you would then in the look do an even or odd technique to grab the field name, vs. its value

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex this pattern can help:

```
(?<identifier>[a-z]+)(?<value>[a-z]+)
```

See how it [works](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28?%3Cidentifier%3E%5Ba-z%5D%2b%29%28?%3Cvalue%3E%5Ba-z%5D%2b%29&i=/firstname%3aBob%20/lastname%3aJones&o=i).

You can iterate on all groups and can extract `identifier` and `value`.